# Condicionar a seleção de um ID

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho a seguinte função AJAX:

```
function exibeUltimaAula(){


  let montaAula = {

    idUsuario: document.querySelector('#id').textContent,
    token: document.querySelector('#token').textContent,
    id: document.querySelector('#ultima-aula').textContent
  };

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var variavel = document.querySelector('#token-servico').innerHTML;

  xhr.open("POST", "http://54.233.209.248:8080/rest/classes/findById", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + variavel);
  xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){

    if(xhr.status == 200){

      console.log(xhr.responseText);

      let aula = xhr.responseText;
      aula = JSON.parse(aula);

      let video = "";
      video += aula.video;
      document.querySelector("#video-aula").innerHTML = video;

      let descricao = "";
      descricao += aula.descricao;
      document.querySelector("#aula-descricao").innerHTML = descricao;

    }

    if(xhr.status =500){
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(montaAula));
}

  setTimeout(exibeUltimaAula, 1000);
```

Esta função insere um ID na tag 1  que é:

```
<p id="ultima-aula"></p>
```

Porém, em outra situação no sistema, eu preciso que este ID venha pra mim via GET, então insiro este id na segunda tag:

```
Tag 2 <p><?=$aula?></p>
```

Estou tendo um conflito em relação a isso, gostaria de saber se tem algum lugar nesse ajax onde eu  consiga fazer uma condição.

A condição seria a seguinte:

Se o ID vier da URL eu uso a tag 2, se ele não vier da URL eu uso a tag 1.

Será que tem como?

Comment: Não consegui ver no código onde a função insere a id como mencionado na pergunta.

Comment: id: document.querySelector('#ultima-aula').textContent essa linha, insere nesta linha <p id="ultima-aula"></p>